# Keeping Spring Cloud Config Secure in an Open Source Application

Tags: spring, security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Some of my services require API secrets in their configurations. My project is open source, so I cannot store these secrets in the main repository.

Spring Cloud Config has the ability to connect to a private git repository to retrieve the secret configuration, but to do so requires credentials which I, again, cannot store in the main repository.

**What is the best practice for storing secrets in an open source application when using Spring Cloud Config?**

Comment: Seems like a Chicken and egg problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both open source and closed source applications, credentials should not be stored with the source code.

Multiple solutions exist to store credentials, you can store them into environment variables, into a property file added in `.gitignore` or if you want a more elaborate solution you can use a dedicated tool such as [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/). There is an interesting official Spring blog post exploring this solution : [Managing Secrets with Vault](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/24/managing-secrets-with-vault).